# Does a subnormal number have an implicit 0?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, mantissa

I'm trying to understand what a subnormal number is and I'm guessing the exponent is fixed at -127 and to make the number smaller the implicit 1 is replaced with an implicit 0. Does this sound right?

Answer (score 1):

In the IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary format, the exponent for a subnormal number is −126, not −127. The leading bit of the significand is indeed zero.

For any of the IEEE-754 binary formats, let:

- *p* be the number of bits in the full significand (“p” for precision, 24 for the 32-bit format), *bias* be the bias used for encoding the exponent (127 for the 32-bit format), and
- *S* be the bit in the sign field, *E* be the bits in the exponent field, and *T* be the bits in the trailing significand field.

If *E* is not all zeros or all ones, the value represented is a normal number. Its value is (−1)<sup>*S*</sup>•2<sup>*E*−*bias*</sup>•(1+2<sup>1−*p*</sup>•T). That term 1+2<sup>1−*p*</sup>•T may be pictured as a one bit followed by a radix point followed by the bits of *T*: “1.*T*”.

If *E* is all zeros, the value represented is zero (if *T* is zero) or a subnormal number. Its value is (−1)<sup>*S*</sup>•2<sup>1−*bias*</sup>•(0+2<sup>1−*p*</sup>•T). Note two changes from the normal value: The exponent is 1−*bias* instead of *E*−*bias*, and the leading bit is 0 instead of 1.

Note the smallest normal values and the subnormal values have an exponent of 1-*bias*, which is 1−127 = −126 for the 32-bit format. When transitioning from normal values to subnormal values, we do not change both the exponent and the leading bit, because that would cause a jump in the representable values. So the subnormal values have the same exponent as the smallest normal values; just the leading bit changes.